# Image rotation with JQuery and rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, jquery-plugins, rotation

I'm searching for a plugin or a simple way to make an image rotatable by dragging (with the mouse) a button on this image.
I want to be able to save the angle rotation too.

Does anyone know how to do it easily please?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might get you started: http://wilq32.adobeair.pl/jQueryRotate/Wilq32.jQueryRotate.html

You should be able to hook up a slider, or a drag handle or something and just call rotate when that changes.